# What is the use case of new Voided Purchases API

Tags: android

Google just launch [Voided Purchases API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/voided-purchases)

> The Google Play Voided Purchases API allows you to revoke access to in-app products that are associated with purchases that a user has voided. The user can void a purchase in the following ways:
>
> - The user requests a refund for their order.
> - The user cancels their order.
> - An order is charged back.

But, I am confused with the use case.

Currently, I have an app with non consumable in-app purchase item (One-time purchase).

Whenever my app starts, I will check whether user has purchased the item, by using the following code.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/master/TrivialDrive/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample/MainActivity.java#L243

I expect `inventory.getPurchase` will return null during next app startup, if user has decided to cancel their purchase order.

So, how does `Voided Purchases API` fit in "user has decided to cancel their purchase order" case?

I thought by using `onQueryInventoryFinished`, we can determine what item is currently owned by user?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Voided Purchases API is intended to be used by applications which utilize a back-end server for the purchase fulfillment.  For example: a special item in a multiplayer game, a virtual currency, or an upgraded membership level.

In these scenarios, the server would otherwise have no knowledge that a previously fulfilled purchase was no longer valid.  This new API allows the server to query for voided purchases and then revoke whatever item/currency/membership was already fulfilled.

In the client-only scenario that you described, this API would be of no use.

Comment: I don’t think this is true: “In these scenarios, the server would otherwise have no knowledge that a previously fulfilled purchase was no longer valid.” The backend’s primary data source are Real-Time Developer Notifications to get purchase status updates. The Voided Purchases API seems to be an additional data source to get details about special scenarios in which a purchase becomes invalid.

Answer (score 1):

The Voided Purchases API fetches a list of purchases that were cancelled, refunded or charged back.

To use it, you need to make an HTTP request which returns a list of voided purchases.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/packageName/purchases/voidedpurchases
```

If the item you want to check for is present in this list then it means that item has been cancelled/refunded/charged back.

Have a look at this [page](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/voidedpurchases/list).

There is no mention of

```
inventory.getPurchase()
```

or

```
onQueryInventoryFinished
```

on that webpage but it is apparent that they won't work.