# Flutter: Am I required to include "Refund Purchases" for my app?

Tags: flutter

I'm using the package `in-app-purchase` to make in app purchases for my Flutter app.

I've been trying to implement a 'Refund' feature using the `InAppPurchase.restorePurchases` for a few days now without luck.

And then I thought: "Does **Restoring a purchase** mean granting the user their rewards upon re-installation **OR** does it mean refunding their purchase?"

So my question is the following: Is offering a refund for all purchases mendatory? And what does Restore Purchases actually do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any policy either from Google or Apple that forces the developers to post any information on their apps regarding refunds.

In either case, the user can ask for a full refund of an app purchase or in-app content, up to 48 hours after the payment was processed, and for some types of content like ebooks, the refund can be even later.

[Manage your app’s orders and issue refunds](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2741495?hl=en)
[Learn about refunds on Google Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2479637?hl=en)

There are also some good answers on StackOverflow about [refunds on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63451542/4605422)

Comment: That settles it then: 'restorePurchases' is only responsible for restoring app features and not money!